# calling a boolean method from another class

Tags: android

I am trying to call a boolean from another class, to check for internet connection.

calling code is

```
public void submit_user(View view){
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_username);
    String user_name = editText.getText().toString();
    EditText pw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_password);
    String pwd = pw.getText().toString();

    MyActivity my = new MyActivity();
    if(my.isConnected()) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

boolean method is:

```
public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)


                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

tried to post error message, but won't let me submit.

new at this, appreciate help. Thank you in advance.

Richard

Comment: ```MyActivity my = new MyActivity();``` this is WRONG. you can't do this with class that is activity.

Comment: The error you are getting is completely different from the question  you are asking. Also you are creating a new instance every time ,so each time the boolean value will be the initial value.

Comment: Change MyActivity my = new MyActivity(); to MyActivity myActivity = ((MyActivity)getApplicationContext());

Comment: so, it has to be from a non-activity class? oh.. beginning to understand

Comment: You can't use new with activity class. and you should consider creating a helper class for checking internet connection instead of using activity class

Comment: Hey, thanks everyone for your help, will need to digest the answers. Let me try it out and revert. Thanks alot, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities
>   before onCreate()

Means `MyActivity` class extending Activity and currently not running.

Instead of calling methods from class which is extending Activity or using other application main components like Services,BroadcastRecivers,... create a normal java class and pass Context of caller class to access System Service from other class. change `isConnected` method as :

```
public boolean isConnected(Context mContext){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  ....
}
```

and pass `view.getContext()` or Activity Context to `isConnected` method :

```
MyActivity my = new MyActivity();
if(my.isConnected(view.getContext())) {
    //do something
}
```

also remove `extends Activity` from `MyActivity` class

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ***new*** with **Activity** class. so try with following ways.

use static method like,

```
public static boolean isConnected(){
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

}

and then access directly like,

```
if(MyActivity.isConnected()) {
    //do something
}
```

> or

create object like,

```
MyActivity myActivity = ((MyActivity)getApplicationContext());
```

then access,

```
 if(myActivity.isConnected()) {
    //do something
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
 }
}
```

Put this method inside simple java class not Activity

Comment: Also this will require context since this will not be in non activity class.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, you are right, now I have an error, cannot resolve method 'getSystemService'. sorry, managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

declare method public static and access using that class name in another class

for example method in ClassOne.java 
and you want to use the from from classone in ClasssTwo.java

simply use ClassOne.isConnceted()